# ARRAYFORMULA not working with custom formula containing IF and COUNTIF

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

I'm running a `=ARRAYFORMULA()` of `=IF()` with a custom formula (`=getRedirect()`), that retrieves original URLs of redirect shortened URLs that are in a cell range, to get the user ID in the original URLs. If URL in cell `B:B` is a redirect shortened URL, it runs the custom formula and outputs the user ID into `C:C` after running a `=MID()` to the output of the custom formula. If URL in cell `B:B` is an original URL, it outputs the user ID into `C:C` after running a `=MID()` on it. The `=IF()` outputs specific error message depending on the cell value in `B:B`.

Here's the custom formula -

```
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'followRedirects': false, 'muteHttpExceptions': false});
  var redirectUrl = response.getHeaders()['Location']; // undefined if no redirect, so...
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  if (redirectUrl) {                                   // ...if redirected...
    var nextRedirectUrl = getRedirect(redirectUrl);    // ...it calls itself recursively...
    Logger.log(url + " is redirecting to " + redirectUrl + ". (" + responseCode + ")");
    return nextRedirectUrl;
  }
  else {                                               // ...until it's not
    Logger.log(url + " is canonical. (" + responseCode + ")");
    return url;
  }
}
```

Here's what I input in C:C -
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($B2:B="","<--- Please insert TikTok video's URL",IF(COUNTIF($B2:B,"*/video/*"),MID($B2:B,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE($B2:B,"/","~",5))+1,19),IFERROR(MID(getRedirect($B2:B),FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(getRedirect($B2:B),"/","~",6))+1,19),"<--- error in URL"))))`

The formula outputs normally without `=ARRAYFORMULA()`. Not sure if it's due to the clash between `=ARRAYFORMULA()` and `=COUNTIF()` in the formula in `C:C`.

Sample sheet with expected outcome - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rJKm5KIT8itZs2AC0wdDZ-CGar4mERu4jzJ3mN7KMb8

Answer (score 0):

To use custom function with `ARRAYFORMULA`, you need to modify you script.
See this [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization)

Comment: Hi @idfurw! @RonM has kindly helped me to modify the script as per the example in the article that you've provided. Unfortunately, it did not work with =arrayformula().